# The named parameter 'options' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app to send data to database where I am using this piece of code and "The named parameter 'options' isn't defined" this problem is appearing.

```
final FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp(
  options: FirebaseOptions(
  googleAppID: '',
  apiKey: '',
  databaseURL: '',
)
);
```

Comment: The [constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseApp/FirebaseApp.html) does indeed not have any `options` argument. What are you trying to do?

Comment: No matter how good answer you write on this user post, he'd never accept it.

Comment: I am trying to send data to data base I am following a tutorial but In my case this error is occurring.

Comment: hy Basketball! do not through rock while you cant help. I have just posted 2 or 3 questions and you are commenting on each post that I never accept answers, lock at the comments on each question I accept all which help me go and first check do not make Stack overflow hell for new one. you are top 2 % of this year but your behavior Is strange for others. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseApp-class.html

`FireBaseApp` has a static method named `.configure` that accepts a `String name` and `FireBaseOptions options` that returns an existing unmodified `Future<FireBaseApp>` or a new configured `Future<FireBaseApp>` asynchronously.